# Elasticsearch Query: format issue when using Auto-interval date histogram aggregation

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation

I'm using [auto-interval date histogram aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.11/search-aggregations-bucket-autodatehistogram-aggregation.html) on an elasticsearch query.
It's working fine except for the format part.

Here's my aggregation parameters with the format option:

```
"aggs": {
  "date": {
    "auto_date_histogram": {
      "field": "created_at",
      "buckets": 31,
      "minimum_interval": "day",
      "format": "yyyy-MM-dd"
    }
  }
}
```

I'm getting: `yyyy-MM-dd1614729600000` instead of a correctly formatted date like `2021-03-03`.

```
{
  key_as_string: 'yyyy-MM-dd1614729600000',
  key: 1614729600000,
  doc_count: 28
}
```

Any idea what i'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is on the mappings of your `created_at` field.

Please post the output of `GET your_index/_mapping`.

I tested your query on a default `date` type field and works as expected.

```
POST kibana_sample_data_ecommerce/_search?size=0
{
  "aggs": {
    "date": {
      "auto_date_histogram": {
        "field": "order_date",
        "buckets": 31,
        "minimum_interval": "day",
        "format": "yyyy-MM-dd"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Response

```
{
  "took" : 4,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "successful" : 1,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 4675,
      "relation" : "eq"
    },
    "max_score" : null,
    "hits" : [ ]
  },
  "aggregations" : {
    "date" : {
      "buckets" : [
        {
          "key_as_string" : "2021-02-11",
          "key" : 1613001600000,
          "doc_count" : 146
        },
        {
          "key_as_string" : "2021-02-12",
          "key" : 1613088000000,
          "doc_count" : 153
        },
        {
          "key_as_string" : "2021-02-13",
          "key" : 1613174400000,
          "doc_count" : 143
        },
        {
          "key_as_string" : "2021-02-14",
          "key" : 1613260800000,
          "doc_count" : 140
        },
        {
          "key_as_string" : "2021-02-15",
          "key" : 1613347200000,
          "doc_count" : 139
        },
        {
          "key_as_string" : "2021-02-16",
          "key" : 1613433600000,
          "doc_count" : 157
        },
        {
          "key_as_string" : "2021-02-17",
          "key" : 1613520000000,
          "doc_count" : 145
        },
        {
          "key_as_string" : "2021-02-18",
          "key" : 1613606400000,
          "doc_count" : 152
        },
        {
          "key_as_string" : "2021-02-19",
          "key" : 1613692800000,
          "doc_count" : 163
        },
        {
          "key_as_string" : "2021-02-20",
          "key" : 1613779200000,
          "doc_count" : 141
        },
        {
          "key_as_string" : "2021-02-21",
          "key" : 1613865600000,
          "doc_count" : 151
        },
        {
          "key_as_string" : "2021-02-22",
          "key" : 1613952000000,
          "doc_count" : 143
        },
        {
          "key_as_string" : "2021-02-23",
          "key" : 1614038400000,
          "doc_count" : 143
        },
        {
          "key_as_string" : "2021-02-24",
          "key" : 1614124800000,
          "doc_count" : 142
        },
        {
          "key_as_string" : "2021-02-25",
          "key" : 1614211200000,
          "doc_count" : 161
        },
        {
          "key_as_string" : "2021-02-26",
          "key" : 1614297600000,
          "doc_count" : 144
        },
        {
          "key_as_string" : "2021-02-27",
          "key" : 1614384000000,
          "doc_count" : 157
        },
        {
          "key_as_string" : "2021-02-28",
          "key" : 1614470400000,
          "doc_count" : 158
        },
        {
          "key_as_string" : "2021-03-01",
          "key" : 1614556800000,
          "doc_count" : 144
        },
        {
          "key_as_string" : "2021-03-02",
          "key" : 1614643200000,
          "doc_count" : 151
        },
        {
          "key_as_string" : "2021-03-03",
          "key" : 1614729600000,
          "doc_count" : 145
        },
        {
          "key_as_string" : "2021-03-04",
          "key" : 1614816000000,
          "doc_count" : 157
        },
        {
          "key_as_string" : "2021-03-05",
          "key" : 1614902400000,
          "doc_count" : 158
        },
        {
          "key_as_string" : "2021-03-06",
          "key" : 1614988800000,
          "doc_count" : 153
        },
        {
          "key_as_string" : "2021-03-07",
          "key" : 1615075200000,
          "doc_count" : 165
        },
        {
          "key_as_string" : "2021-03-08",
          "key" : 1615161600000,
          "doc_count" : 153
        },
        {
          "key_as_string" : "2021-03-09",
          "key" : 1615248000000,
          "doc_count" : 158
        },
        {
          "key_as_string" : "2021-03-10",
          "key" : 1615334400000,
          "doc_count" : 160
        },
        {
          "key_as_string" : "2021-03-11",
          "key" : 1615420800000,
          "doc_count" : 159
        },
        {
          "key_as_string" : "2021-03-12",
          "key" : 1615507200000,
          "doc_count" : 152
        },
        {
          "key_as_string" : "2021-03-13",
          "key" : 1615593600000,
          "doc_count" : 142
        }
      ],
      "interval" : "1d"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You're right, there's an issue with the mapping. I tried with another date field and the formatting works as expected. I don't have access to mappings but I'll talk to the person in charge. Thank you for your help !